# Two different Activites of two different application in a single Fragment?

Tags: android

Is this is possible guys i want to add two different Activities of different application in a Fragment?
For example Video Preview and chat List view in a single view.

Comment: Add? You mean start with an intent? - Yes. If you have the projectfolders from the different applications.

Comment: You are understanding fragments wrong. Activities **host** fragments. More specifically, a `Fragment` is a reusable part of an application that can be used in many activities. I recommend you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to understand `Fragment`s better.

Comment: Thanks Niksn and Miro for your valuable information,im having the project folder niksn and i am trying to combine both application together.first one is video recording and other one is simple xmpp chat application.the concept is to chat while recording the video,how can i achieve this? your information will be useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have two applications in one window. Each application runs under a different window session and cannot share windows. It is possible to display both windows side by side but the window manager has no stable API (it may change in any new version and it already did change in the history), and either each application would need to request that itself or you need root access.

Also, you understand fragments incorrectly. A fragment is hosted inside an acitivity, not the other way around.